# Deploying nextjs to vercel: next server send error Error: Cannot find module 'sharp' Require stack:

Tags: node.js, npm, backend, vercel, sharp

After completing the deployment of my project, I tried to test my backend by sending a post request on my nextjs project, in the backend I used sharp to add a watermark on the user sent image, but when I tested the function the vercel log sent this error message

```
Error: Cannot find module 'sharp' Require stack: .............
```

this is the logs in my vercel

[image]

the project is work properly on my local

anyone can help me with this??

Comment: I'm having the same error. It started with the update of nextJS from v13.5.3 to v13.5.4